# Change the orientation of text on categoryAxis of jqchart

Tags: jqchart

I have a jqxchart where in everything is appearing perfectly.
The only issue remains is of the text on the categoryAxis of the chart.
the text is coming in the horizontal direction and its overlapping with the other text of the chart.
Can any1 please help me changing the orientation of the text that shows on categoryAxis?
Here's the code that I am using

```
function BindServerErrorChart() {
    // prepare chart data
    var sampleData = [
                { Server: 'Server1', Error: 6 },
                { Server: 'Server2', Error: 50 },
                { Server: 'Server3', Error: 31 },
                { Server: 'Server4', Error: 78 },
                { Server: 'Server5', Error: 19 },
                { Server: 'Server6', Error: 60.90 }
                ];


    // prepare jqxChart settings
    var settings = {
        title: "Errors By server",
        description: "",
        showLegend: true,
        enableAnimations: false,
        padding: { left: 20, top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5 },
        titlePadding: { left: 90, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 },
        source: sampleData,
        categoryAxis:
                    {
                        dataField: 'Server',
                        showGridLines: false,
                        flip: false
                    },
        colorScheme: 'scheme01',
        seriesGroups:
                    [
                        {
                            type: 'column',
                            orientation: 'horizontal',
                            columnsGapPercent: 100,
                            toolTipFormatSettings: { thousandsSeparator: ',' },
                            valueAxis:
                            {
                                flip: true,
                                unitInterval: 10,
                                displayValueAxis: true,
                                description: '',
                                formatFunction: function (value) {
                                    return parseInt(value);
                                }
                            },
                            series: [
                                    { dataField: 'Error', displayText: 'Servers' }
                                ]
                        }
                    ]
    };
    // setup the chart
                    $('#ServerErrorChart').jqxChart(settings);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set textRotationAngle: 90
in the categoryAxis settings

Answer (score 1):

I just got the solution to this.
I edited as following.

```
categoryAxis:
{
dataField: 'Server',
showGridLines: false,
flip: true,
textRotationAngle: 90
},
```